# The Last Man On Earth Plot Trick

Tags: plot-explanation, the-last-man-on-earth

I was watching *The Last Man On Earth* S02E05 and I was assuming it was the body of Gordon (Will Ferrell) from episode 1 in the fridge the whole time and Todd was doing cannibalism but then it was revealed that the contents of the fridge was bacon.

Now I want to know whether this wrong assumption (cannibalism) was the writers' intention through the episode or was it just my sick psychopathic(!) imagination?